Вставка элементов в список с шагом методом insert
Есть случайный список:
[8, 5, 2, 5, 2].
По условию задачи необходимо получить новый список, где между каждой парой элементов исходного списка вставляется новый элемент, равный сумме значений соседних элементов:
[8, 13, 5, 7, 2, 7, 5, 7, 2]
Код необходимо реализовать методом insert. Пробую следующий вариант, но безуспешно:
from random import*
seed(35)
n=[randint(0,9) for i in range(5)] 
print(n)
for i in range(len(n)):
     n.insert(i+1,n[i]+n[i+1])
print(n)

Буду признательна за подсказку

Вам нужно суммировать индексы 0 и 1 и вставить в 1, затем 2 и 3 и вставить в 3, затем 4 и 5  и вставить в 5 и т.д.

Благодарю вас ))

В принципе, в вашем коде достаточно исправить одну строчку - сам цикл:
for i in range(0, len(n) * 2 - 2, 2):

Но это в некотором роде хак, это работает в моей версии питона, но может не работать в какой-то другой, лучше переписать на while с ручной проверкой окончания цикла и ручным сдвигом индекса.
В чём суть. При вставке элементов в список весь оставшийся список сдвигается вправо и поэтому вам нужно прибавлять индекс не на 1, а на 2. Но кроме того, сбивается итерирование, поэтому приходится ставить другую границу окончания цикла, заранее правильно рассчитанную. Через while всё делается надёжнее и правильнее.

Спасибо. Буду пробовать. Пока задача решилась методом выше.

Задача решилась методом Stanislav Volodarskiy. Большое спасибо.
from random import*
seed(40)
n=[randint(0,9) for i in range(5)] 
print(n)
for i in range(len(n)):
    if i%2 == 0:
        n.insert(i+1,n[i]+n[i+1])
print(n)


пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Хм, у меня последняя цифра так пропадает )

Блин, действительно ...
